# hough transform error in matlab and openCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv, hough-transform

I have been using the Hough transform in my application both using Matlab and OpenCV/labview and found that for some images, the hough transform gave an obviously wrong line fit (consistently)

Here are the test and overlayed images. The angle seem right, but the rho is off.
[image]

On the image below, you will see the top image tries to fit a line to the left side of the original image and the bottom image fits a line to the right side of the image.

[image]

In Matlab, I call the Hough function through

```
[H1D,theta1D,rho1D] = hough(img_1D_dilate,'ThetaResolution',0.2);
```

in C++, i trimmed the OpenCV HoughLines function so I end up with only the part we are filling the accumulator. Note that because my theta resolution is 0.2, I have 900 angles to analyze. The tabSin and tabCos are defined prior to the function so that they are just a sin and cos of the angle.

Note that these routines generally work well, but just for specific cases it performs the way I have shown.

```
double start_angle = 60.0;
    double end_angle = 120.0;
    double num_theta = 180;
    int start_ang = num_theta * start_angle/180;
    int end_ang = num_theta * end_angle/180;
    int i,j,n,index;
        for (i = 0;i<numrows;i++)
        {
            for (j = 0;j<numcols;j++)
            {
                    if (img[i*numcols + j] == 100)
                {
                    for (n = 0;n<180;n++)
                    {   
                        index = cvRound((j*tabCos[n] + i * tabSin[n])) + (numrho-1)/2;
                        accum[(n+1) * (numrho+2) + index+1]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

TabCos and tabSin are defined in Labview with this code
int32 i;
float64 theta_prec;
float64 tabSin[180];
float64 tabCos[180];

theta_prec = 1/180*3.14159;
for (i = 0;i<180;i++)
{ 
tabSin[i] = sin(i*theta_prec);
tabCos[i] = cos(i*theta_prec);
}

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Any code? I don't like guessing from images :)

Comment: Don't you need another loop for `numrho`?

Comment: the dimensions of the accumulator are numrho and numtheta. in the calculation, we are going through all the thetas and finding the rho that would be associated to it. Then once you have theta and rho, you just increment that bin.

Comment: Now I see your code is from OpenCV sources. I used `cvHoughLines2` with `CV_HOUGH_STANDARD`. The result is flawless: http://imgur.com/x2BNr.png . Maybe there is something wrong with your drawing function?

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code to include a part that is done in labview. The part that is written in C is entirely shown in the first fragment.

and you are right, I actually tried these images back oon OpenCV's actual function, other than a bunch of crashes (probably due to memory leak in the HoughLines function, I seem to be getting decent numbers which are different than the ones coming out of the part I extracted.

Comment: Hello Nimcap!You are absolutely right. After a lot of playing around, I found my display code to be wrong. Not entirely sure what went wrong because it worked for most cases but i'm guessing it has to do with the fact that most my angles are around 90degrees. I used to extract the slope and y-intercept from the theta and rho, and then from those values, calculate x and y s for plotting. There must have been something funny happening in there. Thanks for helping so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: nimcap: how would i give you the points?

Answer (score 1):

I guess i'll put down the answer to this problem.

I was converting the rho and theta into m and b, then computing the values of x and y from the m and b. I believe this may have caused some precision error somewhere.

this error was fixed by obtaining x and y directly from rho and theta rather than going through m and b.

the function is

```
y = -cos(theta)/sin(theta)*x + rho/sin(theta);
```